playwright python how can I catch exception and just gracefully quit
I'm unable to exit a playwright loop cleanly on KeyboardInterrupt/Exception. It is called by subprocess() in our CICD and always fails due to this garble when the system sends <ctrl+c> after running for its slotted time:
(simplified example with google)
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
pip install playwright
playwright install
playwright install-deps
"""
import argparse, json, platform, sys, time
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
url = "https://www.google.no"
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='playwright example')
parser.add_argument('--browser', help='browser type', choices=['chrome','firefox','msedge','webkit'], default='chrome')
parser.add_argument('--headed', help='set to set headed with browser', action='store_true')
args, unknown_args = parser.parse_known_args()
if unknown_args:
    print(f"unknown parameters: {unknown_args}")
    sys.exit(-1)

args.headless = True
if args.headed:
    args.headless = False

if platform.system()!='Darwin' and args.browser=='webkit':
    print("webkit only supported on apple")
    sys.exit(-1)


p = sync_playwright().start()
t0 = time.time()
if args.browser=='firefox':
    browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=args.headless)
elif args.browser=='chrome':
    browser = p.chromium.launch(channel='chrome', headless=args.headless)
elif args.browser=='msedge':
    browser = p.chromium.launch(channel='msedge', headless=args.headless)
elif args.browser=='webkit':
    browser = p.webkit.launch(headless=args.headless)
page = browser.new_page()
searches = ["python", "playwright", "selenium", "requests", "beautifulsoup"]
for search in searches:
    try:
        t1 = time.time()
        page.goto(url)
        try:
            page.get_by_role("button", name="Godta alle").click(timeout=1000)
        except Exception as e:
           pass
        
        page.get_by_label("Søk", exact=True).type(search)
        page.get_by_label("Søk", exact=True).press("Enter")
        page.locator("#tsf").get_by_role("button", name="Søk", exact=True)
        time.sleep(1)
        page.screenshot(path=f"pics/google-{search}.png")
    except Exception:
        browser.close()
        sys.exit(0)

When I exit with <ctrl+c> It fails on closing the browser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dist\testing\exit-test.py", line 59, in <module>
    browser.close()
  File "C:\dist\venvs\testing\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_generated.py", line 13927, in close
    return mapping.from_maybe_impl(self._sync(self._impl_obj.close(reason=reason)))
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\dist\venvs\testing\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_sync_base.py", line 115, in _sync
    return task.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\dist\venvs\testing\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_browser.py", line 192, in close
    raise e
  File "C:\dist\venvs\testing\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_browser.py", line 189, in close
    await self._channel.send("close", {"reason": reason})
  File "C:\dist\venvs\testing\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 59, in send
    return await self._connection.wrap_api_call(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\dist\venvs\testing\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 514, in wrap_api_call
    raise rewrite_error(error, f"{parsed_st['apiName']}: {error}") from None
Exception: Browser.close: Connection closed while reading from the driver

if I just do:
      :
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)

I manage to get it clean sometimes, but mostly:
Exception ignored in: <function BaseSubprocessTransport.__del__ at 0x00000242299C2A20>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dist\python312\Lib\asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 126, in __del__
  File "C:\dist\python312\Lib\asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 104, in close
  File "C:\dist\python312\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 109, in close
  File "C:\dist\python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 795, in call_soon
  File "C:\dist\python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 541, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000242299E8220>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dist\python312\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\dist\python312\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 80, in __repr__
  File "C:\dist\python312\Lib\asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 102, in fileno
ValueError: I/O operation on closed pipe
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-12' coro=<Locator.click() running at C:\dist\venvs\testing\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_locator.py:156> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]> cb=[SyncBase._sync.<locals>.<lambda>() at C:\dist\venvs\testing\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_sync_base.py:111, ProtocolCallback.__init__.<locals>.cb() at C:\dist\venvs\testing\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py:191]>

Any hints greatly appreciated :-)

Instead of args, please hardcode variables to make the script reproducible. We don't know what you used for those args when you ran the script. Thanks. Instead of p = sync_playwright().start(), why not use a with statement so the handle will be closed properly?

Can be anything ex:python test.py --browser=chrome --headed or python test.py --browser=chrome or just python test.py

If you do a proper teardown: 'close pages' -> 'close session' -> 'close browser' then your errors should go away.

This is headless and automated, the raise KeyboardInterrupt("job finished") comes in from another container. No way I can access the Browsers GUI (maybe CDPSession?)

One way could be nest the browser.close() into a try/except and if the exception message is about playwright premature shutdown, just pass.
Something like:
try:
    browser.close()
except Exception as e:
    if 'Connection closed' not in str(e):
        raise
sys.exit(0)

Or you could:

grab all the asyncio coroutines
collect the ones which belong to playwright (with inspect-fu)
for each collected coro: task.cancel()
to prevent making your whole project asnyc, create a decorator which resolves the asnyc method to sync result. That is possible with the nest_asyncio package which overrides the default behavior which prevents nesting an asyncio coro into an another

The latter is prettier but way more complicated than just ignoring the playwright premature shutdown exception messages.
